# MediaPlayer в сервисе или в активити? С целью передавать в notification

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notification, android-mediaplayer

У меня сейчас `MediaPlayer` реализован в самом активити и все операции с ним происходят в активити. У меня появилась нужда при сворачивании приложения продолжить воспроизведение в окошке уведомлений `notification` как в ВК. Интересует то, каким образом все это должно работать чтобы все было как надо? Если я вынесу `MediaPlayer` в сервис и когда приложение будет в состоянии `onPause` буду запускать `notification` и туда передавать для управления состояние `MediaPlayer` из сервиса, будет ли это правильным подходом?

Comment: Да, будет правильно. Плеер не должен зависеть от жизненного цикла активити и должен распологаться в сервисе. Активити информацию от сервиса может получать разными способами, но напрямую с плеером взаимодействовать не должно.

Comment: Можете вынести в ответ, отмечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, будет правильно. Плеер не должен зависеть от жизненного цикла активити и должен располагаться в сервисе. Активити информацию от сервиса может получать разными способами, но напрямую с плеером взаимодействовать не должно.